# Upload shapefile through GeoServer REST API?

Tags: fme-form, geoserver-rest-api

I am trying to upload a shapefile to GeoServer over the REST API by using FME.

This should be possible with the HTTPCaller! I am using the following option: - HTTP-methode: PUT

Upload from data

[image: FME interface]

But I get an HTTP 415 error:

[image]

I have access to the given url. So what is the problem here?

Does someone has experience in uploading shapefiles to GeoServer with FME?

Comment: The HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type client error response code indicates that the server refuses to accept the request because the payload format is in an unsupported format.

Answer (score 3):

I found out that the URL was not correct. I need to add ...**/file.shp** so that Geoserver (REST) knows external data will come. Furthermore, I need all files of the shape. So I have to zip all files and to define "application/zip" as content-type.

Now it works. New data will be published on the server and the layer is created automatically in Geoserver.